# Azure Cloud Services - File integrity monitoring possible?

Tags: azure

We're hosting web apps in Azure, using cloud services rather than VMs. We've had a question recently about file integrity monitoring.

Our belief is that this isn't possible unless you're running a full VM, as all the FIM tools need to be installed on the server like a normal program. This isn't really possible here.

Has anyone had any experience with this, or come across Azure specific products that are able to check PaaS cloud services? I've come up empty!

Comment: File Integrity Monitoring is now offered as a service and available in the Azure Security Center: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-file-integrity-monitoring